# Copy collection items to another collection in .NET

Tags: .net, vb.net, collections

In .NET (VB), how can I take all of the items in one collection, and add them to a second collection (without losing pre-existing items in the second collection)? I'm looking for something a little more efficient than this:

```
For Each item As Host In hostCollection1
    hostCollection2.Add(item)
Next
```

My collections are generic collections, inherited from the base class -- Collection(Of )

Comment: Hello Matt, the best answer is not more the best ! Look user4951 answer. It works correctly.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You can use AddRange: `hostCollection2.AddRange(hostCollection1)`.

Comment: 'AddRange' is not a member of 'Collection'.

Answer (score 4):

I know you're asking for VB, but in C# you can just use the constructor of the collection to initialize it with any IEnumerable.  For example:

```
List<string> list1 = new List<string>();
list1.Add("Hello");
List<string> list2 = new List<string>(list1);
```

Perhaps the same kind of thing exists in VB.

Comment: But will pre-existing items in list2 be lost? I'm trying to add to the second collection, not exactly duplicate the first collection.

Comment: Oh sorry, I misunderstood.  In that case, I would use the AddRange method on my list2 object.

Comment: You just added to your post that you are using the base Collection class.  In this case, none of the AddRange solutions are going to work.  If you are using .NET 3.5, we could go the extension method route...

Comment: I am using 3.5, but I didn't even know about extension methods. I don't think it's the route I'm going to take, but definitely pretty cool! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Don't forget that you will be getting a reference and not a copy if you initialize your List2 to List1.  You will still have one set of strings unless you do a deep clone.

Answer (score 2):

I always use the `List<T>.AddRange(otherList<T>)` function. Again, if this is a list of  objects, they will be references the same thing.

You have not specified what sort of collection though, AddRange doesn't exist in CollectionBase inherited objects

Answer (score 2):

This is available when one use an `IList`. But `AddRange` method is not available in `Collection`. I thought of casting `Collection` to `List`, but it is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

List.CopyTo(T[]); maybe?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t69dktcd.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Ben's solution does exist for VB.Net:

```
Dim collection As IEnumerable(Of T)    
Dim instance As New List(collection)
```

Here is the linked [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fkbw11z0.aspx).

However, one thing I would be concerned with is whether or not it does a shallow copy or a deep copy.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you want both collections to modify the same set of objects, then each object is going to have to be copied to the Heap. Maybe you can describe your scenario of how this is impacting your performance and we can find a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

`Array.Copy` may solve your problem.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure for this one

Why not just do this

```
    Dim newlines = _singSongs.ToList
```

That .tolist means it creates a whole new list

Comment: This would overwrite pre-existing items in the second collection, which OP wants to avoid.