# How to create a reference of a list that is only modified when desired?

Tags: vb.net, list, winforms

I have two `WinForms`. In one WinForm, I made a `List` of class objects (called a `Question`). I'm trying to copy that list to a modal dialog form being invoked with `.ShowDialog`. See the relevant parts below.

```
Public Class frmNewGame
Friend lstQuestions As New List(Of Question)

....

Private Sub btnConfigAdv_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnConfigAdv.Click

    Using frmStackConfig As New frmAdvancedStack
        frmStackConfig.lstStackQuestions = lstQuestions

        If frmStackConfig.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
            ' We OK'd the Dialog Window, so now make that form's lstQuestions, THIS form's list of questions.
            ' Additionally, recount and redraw the stats.
            lstQuestions = frmStackConfig.lstStackQuestions

        End If

    End Using
End Sub

....
End Class
```

As you can see, I'm trying to copy the main. On the now DialogForm `frmStackConfig`, I have code on what should be modifying THAT FORM'S copy of the list:

```
lstStackQuestions(dgvQuestions.SelectedRows(0).Cells("dgcQuestionCount").Value).QuestionID = frmFindQuestion.intQuestionNumber
```

On the first half of the form, the code that should be modifying the main form's list should ONLY be copied/modified when the dialog form catches a `DialogResult.OK`. However, the main form's list seems to be modified even if a `DialogResult.Cancel` is being sent.

I found a question/answer that seemed to point me in the right direction of using a copy of the list to make a reference and not modify the main form: [Copy collection items to another collection in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/147416/copy-collection-items-to-another-collection-in-net) and I attempted to do the following with it:

```
        For Each item In lstQuestions
            frmStackConfig.lstStackQuestions.Add(item)
        Next
```

Additionally, I tried both `.AddRange` and `.CopyTo` but I'm given the same result. Even when invoking a `DialogResult.None` or `DialogResult.Cancel`, the main form is still pulling and copying the modal form's copy of the list. The desired result should be that modal form's list collection should ONLY be copied when the parent form catches a `DialogResult.OK`

How should I go about making a reference of the list as to make sure it's not going to be modified by the sub form?

Comment: Classes are reference type. Take a look at [Value Types and Reference Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/data-types/value-types-and-reference-types?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235)

Comment: `Dim a = New MyClass()` then `Dim b = a`; both `a` and `b` points to the same instance of object. You may want to implement [prototype design pattern](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/prototype). (For example by implementing [IClonable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.icloneable?view=net-5.0&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) interface.)

Comment: @RezaAghaei Thanks but I was hoping for something in VB.NET. But it took me a minute but I found the "original" documentation of this method for VB on MSDN: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.memberwiseclone?view=net-5.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a copy of an object then you have to actually create a copy of that object. If you don't have code that creates a new `List(Of Question)` object anywhere then you aren't creating a copy. The simplest option is to just call `ToList`:

```vb
Dim copy = original.ToList()
```

Another option is to create the new list explicitly and then populate it:

```vb
Dim copy As New List(Of Question)

copy.AddRange(original)
```